# splitting a string over multiple pipe signs

Tags: java, split

Very embarrassing but I cannot split a string containing multiple pipes over the pipes:

```
45 ||| naive but I cannot split a string containing
```

This fails, and I don't know why:

```
String split[] = st.split("\\|\\|\\|");
System.out.println(split[1]);
Output: 5
```

What I expect is:

```
naive but I cannot split a string containing
```

Any comments?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal compilable example? As you can see in Soumitri's answer, the split _should_ work.

Comment: I ran your code and it came out as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran this code and here is what I got :

```
String str = "45 ||| naive but I cannot split a string containing";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("\\|\\|\\|")));
```

> **Output :**
>   [45 ,  naive but I cannot split a string containing]

So clearly, it is splitting the string.